# VIEW SERVER STATE equivalent in Azure Sql Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

All,

I'm trying to connect Silk Test Workbench to Azure Sql Server.  However, they only give instructions for connection to Sql Server.  I figure it might work, and it seems to, as it was able to create all of its tables in the database, and use them..

however..

Silk Test needs to be able to run some of its database checks, and it needs some permissions..

[image: Silk Error]

so I tried `GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO tester;`.

No dice.

It gives me the error: `Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server`.

so I figure I might be able to do something else somewhere to be able to give it the permissions it needs.

Suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the [Silk Test Workbench release notes](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/silk-test/190/en/silktest-190-releasenotes-en.pdf), I don't see Azure SQL Database listed as a supported platform. `VIEW SERVER STATE` is not a grantable permission. You could probably use a Managed SQL Server instance or SQL Server on an Azure VM instead. The notes also say " If you have questions about newer releases and versions of supported software or generally about software not mentioned here, please don't hesitate to contact Micro Focus for guidance.
."

Answer (score 3):

Please contact Silk Test's manufacturer and ask them what they want to inspect.  Many of the things that require VIEW SERVER STATE in SQL Server are available (in some form) in SQL Azure though often they are scoped at the level of a database since that's the normal unit of sale.

If the ISV (Micro Focus) would like guidance from Microsoft on how to adjust their app to also work on SQL Azure, that can be arranged as needed.  It benefits everyone if it just works.  Here's the current comparison chart for SQL Azure vs. SQL Server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features

(I don't believe view server state is exposed to customers on Managed Instance either, but I have not yet found a public doc stating that explicitly for you to reference).

Best of luck,
Conor Cunningham
Architect, SQL Team